# Testing Flask WTForms validators without repeating code

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have written a relatively simple web app using Flask and WTForms with standard and custom form validators. I am now trying to learn Python testing. I have written the following tests.py file that works fine with unittest, but has redundancy. Is there a better, more effecient, more pythonic (DNRY) way to do this? I've looked at some pytest tutorials and wonder if fixtures would help, but I cannot quite understand them. And I assume there is a more pythonic way to do this with unittest. It seems I need a method to which I can pass the different dict arguments, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

```
from fly_app import app
import unittest

class FlaskTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_city_code(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        response = tester.post('/flight_search/extensive', data=dict(origin="xxxx"))
        self.assertIn(b'That does not appear to be a valid city code', response.data)

    def test_code_pairs(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        response = tester.post('/flight_search/extensive', data=dict(origin="HFD", destination="CAS"))
        self.assertIn(b'This origin-destination pair is not in searchable cache', response.data)

    def test_duration_range(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        response = tester.post('/flight_search/extensive', data=dict(origin="MSP", destination="NYC", min_duration=20))
        self.assertIn(b'Number must be between 1 and 15', response.data)

    def test_duration_integer(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        response = tester.post('/flight_search/extensive', data=dict(origin="MSP", destination="NYC", min_duration='abc'))
        self.assertIn(b'Not a valid integer value', response.data)

    def test_duration_pair(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        response = tester.post('/flight_search/extensive', data=dict(origin="MSP", destination="NYC", min_duration=10, max_duration=7))
        self.assertIn(b'Maximum trip length cannot be less than minimum', response.data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you create a custom asserter method (`assertExtensiveFlightSearchGivesError(self, data, expected_error_message)`) to remove some of the duplication:

```
class FlaskTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertExtensiveFlightSearchGivesError(self, data, expected_error_message):
        response = test_client.post("/flight_search/extensive", data=data)
        self.assertEqual(4xx, response.status_code)
        self.assertIn(expected_error_message, response.data, "extensive flight search did not contain expected error message")

    def test_city_code(self):
        self.assertExtensiveFlightSearchGivesError(
            {'origin': 'xxx'},
            b'That does not appear to be a valid city code'
        )

    def test_code_pairs(self):
        self.assertExtensiveFlightSearchGivesError(
            {'origin': "HFD", 'destination': "CAS"},
            b'This origin-destination pair is not in searchable cache'
        )

    # ... and so on
```

You could also collect all the test cases together and use `.subTest()`:

```
TEST_CASES = [
    ({'origin': 'xxx'}, b'That does not appear to be a valid city code'),
    ({'origin': "HFD", 'destination': "CAS"}, b'This origin-destination pair is not in searchable cache')
]

class FlaskTestCase2(unittest.TestCase):
    def assertExtensiveFlightSearchGivesError(self, data, expected_error_message):
        response = test_client.post("/flight_search/extensive", data=data)
        self.assertEqual(4xx, response.status_code)
        self.assertIn(expected_error_message, response.data, "extensive flight search did not contain expected error message")

    def test_all_error_cases(self):
        for data, expected_error_message in TEST_CASES:
            with self.subTest():
                self.assertExtensiveFlightSearchGivesError(data, expected_error_message)
```

But in your case, IMO the topmost code example is clearer.

Comment: I implemented your code as in first example, and it works with minor changes:
`response = app.test_client().post(...)`
`self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code) #I do not understand your intent with '4xx'. This seemed to break code, even if I changed it to 404`
Can you explain '4xx'?
`{'origin': 'xxxX'} # 4th 'x' is needed although not in caps because 'XXX' is a valid IATA city code`
Thanks. I may play around with your 2nd answer as well. Any idea why custom assert method is not in [unittest documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)?

Comment: The ``4xx`` just means "some http client error", since that is likely what your app returns in those cases.